# grep for line containing jboss- until next /

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to grep out of a init script status, just the jboss directory.

So in the stdout there is this line:

```
JBOSS_CMD_START = ulimit -c 2500000; cd /home/blah; /apps/jboss-eap-5.1.2/jboss-as/bin/run.sh -c jboss-blahtest -b 1.1.2.3 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1
```

And out of that, I am trying to grep just the directory, up until /jboss-as, so the results would be:

```
/apps/jboss-eap-5.1.2/jboss-as/
```

The problem is the jboss version can be a number of things, so I need to get from /apps/jboss- to /jboss-as/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -oE '/apps/jboss-eap-[^/]+/jboss-as/'
```

Answer (score 4):

One option

```
grep -Eo '/[^[:space:]]+jboss-as/'
```

Answer (score 4):

`grep -oE '\S+/jboss-as/` should do it.